# java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer) error when i am trying to send file in WebSocket

Tags: java, android, sockets, websocket

any one can help me with this error `java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)`
my code

Iam trying to send apk file or any thing else but he refuce send sometimes send this error or nothing happening

```
 private void sendFile(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, String filename) throws IOException {
        String statusLine = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" + "\r\n";
        String serverdetails = "Server: Java HTTPServer";
            String contentLengthLine,contentTypeLine = "";
            if(filename.endsWith(".apk")) {
                 contentTypeLine = "Content-type: application/vnd.android.package-archive\r\n";
            }
            Log.d("available", String.valueOf(inputStream.available()));
        contentLengthLine = "Content-Length: " + (Long.MAX_VALUE-Integer.MAX_VALUE) + "\r\n";

            outputStream.write(statusLine.getBytes());
            outputStream.write(serverdetails.getBytes());
            outputStream.write(contentTypeLine.getBytes());
            outputStream.write(contentLengthLine.getBytes());
            outputStream.write("Connection: close\r\n".getBytes());
            outputStream.write("\r\n".getBytes());

        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                int count;

                while ((count = inputStream.read(b)) >0) {
                    outputStream.write(b);

                }
        Log.d("second","done");
                inputStream.close();
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
        }
```

Comment: That error message usually indicates the remote end of the socket closed the connection or there are network issues between you and the remote end.

Comment: i try use it on chrome it work but when i try using in mobile browser it crashes like that and i send file with mime type apk chrome read mime type as document

Comment: Maybe an extension is blocking it?  Or antivirus?  It could also indicate the remote program crashed and the socket was reset.